# Set operation allowed?

Tags: general-topology

> [image]

Suppose (WLOG) instead, $x \in E$, but $x \notin A$. So $x \in B$ by assumption that $E \subset A \cup B.$ This proves $E \subset B$. Similar argument shows $E \subset A$. But also we cannot have $x \in E$ and $x \notin A$ or $x \notin B$ because this violates $E \subset A \cup B.$

I didn't use the connectedness of $E$ at all…so I am worried.

As a side note, is the operation allowed for any set? this is for any set?

> $X \subset C \iff X \cup D \subset C \cup D$
>
> $X \subset C \iff X \cap D \subset C \cap D$

Comment: The same statement with "$A$ and $B$ disjoint" replaced with "$A\cap E$ and $A\cap B$ disjoint" might be your *definition* of connected ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $E=E\cap(A\cup B)$, which follows from the hypothesis. Then
$$
E=(E\cap A)\cup(E\cap B)
$$
and $(E\cap A)\cap(E\cap B)=E\cap(A\cap B)=\emptyset$.

Thus we have written $E$ as the disjoint union of two open sets in $E$, precisely $E\cap A$ and $E\cap B$. What does connectedness of $E$ imply at this point?

---

About the other part of the question, you are surely allowed to say
$$
X\subset C \implies X\cup D\subset C\cup D
$$
but the converse implication does not hold: just consider two disjoint non empty sets $X$ and $C$ and take $D=X\cup C$. Then $X\cup D\subset C\cup D$ (they're equal, actually), but $X$ is not a subset of $C$.

For the intersection the situation is similar; the counterexample is obtained with $D=\emptyset$.

Comment: I just wrote something like this, except I denoted $E = [\cup_{x \in A \cap E, x \notin B} \{ x\} \cap E ]\bigcup  [\cup_{y \in B \cap E, y \notin A} \{ y\} \cap E]$

Comment: But what you wrote basically is the answer because $E \cap A$ and $E \cap B$ separates $E$.

Comment: @sidht That notation is too complicated, isn't it? Yes, the two sets separate $E$, so one is empty and the other is $E$. Therefore…

Comment: not connected, I got a paper cut in one of my fingers, so probably why I can't interpret my own thoughts properly

Answer (score 1):

You have not proved  that $E\subseteq B$, merely that some $x\in E$ is in one of $A,B$ (this is trivial, and not entirely true: it could be that $E=\emptyset$, which you have tacitly excluded).

Instead, you can argue by contraposition as follows: suppose $E$ has a point in each of $A,B$. Then try to show directly from the definition that it follows that it is not connected.

As for your side question, certainly not. Just consider $D=X$ for the first one and $D=\emptyset$ for the second.

Comment: what if they are proper subsets? (regarding the little comment).

Comment: @sidht: then the implication from left to right does not hold (if the left side holds), if $D=X\cup C$ and $D=\emptyset$ ($\Rightarrow$ does hold for non-strict inclusions, naturally). $\Leftarrow$ doesn't hold either.

Comment: That's only if the sets are the trivial sets right?

Comment: @sidht: absolutely not. If you have some $x$ which is not in any of $X,C,D$, the you add $x$ to all of them and all the inclusions (strict or not) will remain just the same.

Comment: So then when does ($\implies$) hold? That seems like the more practical one.

Comment: It holds for $\subseteq$. Really, just draw a Wenn diagram and check it for yourself.